# Apple Watch can detect my approach?

Tags: apple-watch

Apple Watch, I think third gen.

On it's charger near the front door of the house, both on a huge pillow.  Face is pointed up.

iPhone is charging at the opposite side of the house, so neither one is moving.

When I get about two meters from the watch, the face lights up.  This has happened several times.  Is this just coincidence, or is it responding to the extremely small vibrations of my approach?  Or some other method?

Hard to attribute it to the accelerometer, since it often seems reluctant to light up when I  am wearing it and lift my hand to check the time.

I believe I've seen it happen on a fixed surface as well, but I suppose those would actually vibrate more than a pillow.

Comment: RE: "both on a huge pillow" -- From a fire safety standpoint that is a very foolish thing to do!

Comment: I know it gets quite warm, but it does not get hot enough to ignite or melt synthetic fibers.

Comment: It's not just the temperature, if the charger malfunctions and shorts out within the device or cable there is potential of fire risk. As a general rule any charging device plugged into electricity should be on a hard dry non-flammable surface.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Watch have proximity sensors on the wrist side and face side. It’s how you can silence notifications and sounds and turn off the display by placing your hand over the display.

Nightstand mode alters the point at which the display lights when sensors see a change in proximity of an object and also more sensitive to nudges.

[Nudging the watch or table (or in your case, bed or floor) also works as well to light the display in nightstand mode.](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/alarms-apd27ce65478/watchos)

Comment: That would not explain it lighting up when I am a couple of meters away, and NOT lighting up when I lift it to my face while lying in bed.

Comment: Is it on the charger when you lift to your face? @WGroleau

Comment: No, on my wrist.  It's only on the charger when low or when I'm in the shower.  (I know it's waterproof, but I don't like it trapping water against my skin.)

Comment: My answer only makes sense in watch stand  mode, on the wireless charger. I thought that was the whole premise of your question TBH...